# error 1001 while uploading video via dropbox sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to upload video on drop box.
So i've gone through [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios#uploading) reference.
Authentication is successful. But getting error that File not exist.

code is as below

```
if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
}
NSString *destDir = @"/My App";
NSLog(@"file name:%@ path:%@",[player.contentURL lastPathComponent],[player.contentURL absoluteString]);
[self.restClient uploadFile:[[player.contentURL absoluteString] lastPathComponent] toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:[player.contentURL absoluteString]];
```

and getting following output:

> file name:My Video.mov
>   path:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4C6FB9BE-FF47-47D6-B9E9-D832534D122A/Documents/My%20Video.mov
>   2015-06-01 17:07:55.239 Test App[2733:310902] [WARNING] DropboxSDK:
>   File does not exist
>   (file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4C6FB9BE-FF47-47D6-B9E9-D832534D122A/Documents/My%20Video.mov)
>   2015-06-01 17:07:55.252 Test App[2733:310902] File upload failed with
>   error: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=1001 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (dropbox.com error 1001.)" UserInfo=0x14ebd270
>   {destinationPath=/My App/My%20Video.mov,
>   sourcePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4C6FB9BE-FF47-47D6-B9E9-D832534D122A/Documents/My%20Video.mov}

Answer (score 0):

absoluteString doesn't return the path of a file URL. Have a guess what the method that returns the path might be called.

Answer (score 0):

absoluteString returns the URL as a string and not the path of the file. What you need is:

```
NSString *filePath=[player.contentURL path];
```

This will return:

```
var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4C6FB9BE-FF47-47D6-B9E9-D832534D122A/Documents/My%20Video.mov
```

Which is the actual path of the file.